# ggplot to png - automatically stretching image

Tags: r, image, ggplot2, png

I am generating a `ggplot plot` and saving it as `.png` image. While the plot generated in Rstudio stretches according to the values in y-axis, I get a square looking image when I save it as `.png`.

How to get the best stretched image automatically in `.png` form?

```
# Function to store ggplot plot object as .png image file
savePlot <- function(myPlot, filename) {
  png(filename)
  print(myPlot)
  dev.off()
}

# ggplot object
normalized_bar_plot = ggplot(dat, aes(factor(temp), norm, fill = type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + ylab("Normalized count")+xlab(features[i])+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")

filename = paste0("image_", features[i], ".png")
savePlot(normalized_bar_plot, filename)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For saving `ggplot` figures, I would use `ggsave`. By default this picks up the size of the plot device. So if you set your aspect ratio correct in the plot device on screen, this will translate to the saved image file. In addition, it supports setting the width, height, and dpi of the image via the `width`, `height` and `dpi` input arguments.

For example:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(factor(temp), norm, fill = type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + ylab("Normalized count")+xlab(features[i])+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
# ggsave will save the last generated image, it will also pick up which file format
# to use from the file extension (e.g. png).
ggsave('~/saved_image.png', width = 16, height = 9, dpi = 100)
```

Comment: That is a better option in general. But I am stuck on an older version of R on server (with no install rights) which doesn't support `ggsave`.
I got this error message

`package ‘ggsave’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1)`

Also, I don't want to specify dimensions manually. It should choose the dimensions based on aesthetics.

Comment: `ggsave` is not a separate package, but a function in `ggplot2`.

Comment: And automatically choosing the right aspect ratio based on the plot is not very trivial, and also very dependent on your specific data type. To my knowledge there is no function that does this. You can however try to come up with something yourself.