# How to scale ggplot annotation_custom layer with plotting device size?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I'd like to plot multiple ggplots that have annotation layers using plot_grid or a similar function and keep the relative size/position of the annotation layer the same when plotting. The following is an example:

```
# Generate scatter plot with ggplot.
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000),
                   y = rnorm(1000))
p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()


# Build annotation table with gridExtra::tableGrob().
library(gridExtra)
mytable <- summary(data)
tab <- tableGrob(mytable, rows=NULL, theme=tt)

# Extract x and ylims for positioning table with ggplot_build(). 
xrange <- unlist(ggplot_build(p1)$layout$panel_params[[1]][1])
yrange <- unlist(ggplot_build(p1)$layout$panel_params[[1]][8])
xmin = min(xrange)
xmax = max(xrange)
xdelta = xmax-xmin
ymin = min(yrange)
ymax = max(yrange)
ydelta = ymax-ymin

# Add annotation table to plot.
p2 <- p1 + annotation_custom(tab, xmin = xmin-0.55*xdelta, xmax,
                                  ymin = ymin+0.55*ydelta, ymax)
p2
```

```
# Generate figure with multiple plots using cowplot::plot_grid(). 
library(cowplot)
fig <- plot_grid(p2,p2,p2,p2, labels = "auto")
fig
```

Please help me keep the scale and position of the annotation layer the same in the final figure. Ideally, this could be done in the order of my example: make a plot with annotation, plot multiple plots, but I understand if this is not possible.

### Edit.

Scaling the plotting device does not seem to fix the problem.

```
## Exploring changing the device size.

# I think the default device size is 7x7 inches. 
png("default_size.png",width = 7, height = 7, res = 300, units = "in")
p2
dev.off()
```

```
# Plot2x
png("2x_size.png",width = 14, height = 14, res = 300, units = "in")
p2
dev.off()
```

```
# Plot3x
png("3x_size.png",width = 21, height = 21, res = 300, units = "in")
p2
dev.off()
```

Comment: Your question actually doesn't make sense to me. what the output looks like depends on the width and height that you provide to export function (I think you are working in RStudio and  using GUI to export). Just increase the width and height by factor of 2 or whatever you desire.

Comment: Frustrated because your comment that the question does not make sense is not productive. How can I revise to make the question more clear? However you may have pointed out the crux of the problem. As I illustrate in my edit, when changing the plotting device size the annotation layer does not seem to be scaled with the plot. I think I'm missing something fundamental, but looking for what this is.

Comment: Searching for fixed annotated tables/text on ggplot regardless of scale/size, seems that your question is very much so legit. As I said, and provided the answer, using the right width and height can address the problem but that's rather a "hacky" solution. I am curious if there is a solution that would work for this problem and is not dependent of the plot size/setup.

Comment: Look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40461852/ggplot-to-png-automatically-stretching-image

Comment: Thanks for the ggsave solution. I have also been unable to find a better solution, but I think gtable may hold some solutions: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/gtable.html.

Comment: you're welcome. You may start an issue on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ggsave()` and defining appropriate `width` and `height` this worked for me;

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
set.seed(123) #make the result reproducible

#avoid using data as your dataframe name
mydf <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000),
                   y = rnorm(1000))  

plt <- ggplot(mydf, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()

mytable <- summary(mydf)
mytab <- tableGrob(mytable, rows=NULL) #theme = tt? tt is not defined!

xrange <- unlist(ggplot_build(plt)$layout$panel_params[[1]][1])
yrange <- unlist(ggplot_build(plt)$layout$panel_params[[1]][8])
xmin = min(xrange)
xmax = max(xrange)
xdelta = xmax-xmin
ymin = min(yrange)
ymax = max(yrange)
ydelta = ymax-ymin

tplt <- plt + annotation_custom(tab, xmin = xmin-0.55*xdelta, xmax, 
                                     ymin = ymin+0.55*ydelta, ymax) 

mygrobs <- grid.arrange(tplt, tplt, tplt, tplt,
                        nrow = 2)

ggsave("filename.jpeg", plot = mygrobs,
       scale = 1, width = 15, height = 10, units = "in",
       dpi = 300)
```